# Создать список динамически

Tags: javascript

```js
function createUL(){
  var body = document.body;
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  body.appendChild(ul);
   var li = document.createElement('li');
  while(true){
      var text = prompt('Введите текст', '');

      if(text == null || text == ''){
        break
      };
       li.textContent = text;
       ul.appendChild(li)
  };
};


createUL();
```

Не могу создать список динамически :(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не работало, потому что изначально создавался всего один li...

Сколько элементов нужно добавить - столько и нужно создать. Надо было поставить создание элемента внутри цикла, чтобы на каждом круге создавать новый.

```js
function createUL(){
  var body = document.body;
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  while(true){
    var text = prompt('Введите текст', '');      
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    if(text == null || text == ''){
      break;
    }

    li.textContent = text;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }  
  body.appendChild(ul);
}

createUL();
```

P.s. после `}` можно не ставить ;

Comment: Здравствуйте спасибо за помощь